# Add an option for the user to edit the legend on Map Box in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

In the Map Box app on Power Bi app there is an option for a Legend but unfortunately the legend can't be edited [showing legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGGvW.png). As a user, I would like to have the option to edit the legend by changing the number of entries from 6 measures to a number specified by the user, change the background of the legend, change the font color, size and type.
Is this possible to add these edits for users?

Comment: Probably not possible unless you're willing to write a new custom visual.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no ability to customize the legend with the Mapbox visual for Power BI, however, in future updates, you will be able to change the font color and size, as well as position the legend at the top, bottom, left, or right of the visual.